# Max values in Pandas database to return corresponding values in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

I have 2 pandas dataframes with identical rows and columns but different values and I am trying to use the maximum value from each row of one dataframe and return the value from the corresponding location in the other dataframe.

For example:

```
A = DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape((3, 3)), index=['d1', 'd2', 'd3'], columns=['s1', 's2', 's3'])

B = DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 3), index=['d1', 'd2', 'd3'], columns=['s1', 's2', 's3'])
```

gives something like:

```
     s1   s2   s3               s1      s2     s3 
d1    0    1    2       d1   -0.02    0.01   0.05
d2    3    4    5       d2    0.01   -0.03  -0.03 
d3    6    7    8       d3    0.04   -0.06   0.02
```

I can get the max values of B with 'B.max(axis=1)', but I want to return the corresponding values from A. I'm looking for something like:

```
d1   2
d2   3
d3   6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK you can use [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) to compare against the `max` values and use this boolean mask against df `A`:

```
In [265]:
A = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape((3, 3)), index=['d1', 'd2', 'd3'], columns=['s1', 's2', 's3'])
​
B = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 3), index=['d1', 'd2', 'd3'], columns=['s1', 's2', 's3'])

In [271]:
A

Out[271]:
    s1  s2  s3
d1   0   1   2
d2   3   4   5
d3   6   7   8

In [272]:
B

Out[272]:
          s1        s2        s3
d1 -0.171054 -0.608554  0.168851
d2 -0.514654 -2.281136  1.706951
d3 -1.193330  0.238856  0.770068

In [277]:
A[B.eq(B.max(axis=1), axis=0)]

Out[277]:
    s1  s2  s3
d1 NaN NaN   2
d2 NaN NaN   5
d3 NaN NaN   8
```

You can then get the row-wise max on the above:

```
In [279]:
A[B.eq(B.max(axis=1), axis=0)].max(axis=1)

Out[279]:
d1    2.0
d2    5.0
d3    8.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I was after. Perhaps I wasn't clear. I want to use the max numbers for each row found in B and return the raw numbers from A that are in the same corresponding location in the dataframe. So if (d1, s3) is the max for the d1 row in B, I would like (d1, s3) from A to be returned, 2.

Comment: So you want `A[B== B.max(axis=1)]`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This sounds right but I'm getting NaNs. Am I missing something?

Comment: It masks the df, you can call `max` again on it, I'll update